# Text inside parbox is invisible

Tags: parbox

The text inside the \parbox isn't showing up on the compiled pdf. What is the solution to this problem?

Best regards from Sweden.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\parbox[h!][\textheight][t]{\textwidth}{

\parbox[h!][\textheight][t]{0.17\textwidth}{
\vspace*{0.075\textheight}
\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}
\rule[\textheight]{1pt}{0.85\textheight}
}

\parbox[h!][0.85\textheight][t]{0.76\textwidth}{
\vspace{12em}
{\huge Assignment report} \\[0.1cm]
{\Large{EDA331, Computer Systems Engineering}} \\[0.8cm]
{\Large \bf Optimizing Hardware and Software \\
in Scientific Computing} \\ [1cm]
{\Large Ali Mohamed \& Ali Mohamud\\
almoha@student.chalmers.se | 
almoh@student.chalmers.se \\[0.8cm]
\today}
}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest that you forget about `\parbox`es and rather describe what you are trying to achieve: do you want to insert a frontispiece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `h` option to `\parbox`. Here's a simpler version. Adjust the spacing to your liking.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vrule width 1pt\hspace{2em}%
\begin{minipage}[b][\textheight][t]{.76\textwidth}
\raggedright
\vspace{12em}
{\huge Assignment report\\}
{\Large{EDA331, Computer Systems Engineering}\\}
{\Large \bf Optimizing Hardware and Software \\
in Scientific Computing\\[1cm]}
{\Large Ali Mohamed \& Ali Mohamud\\
user@x.y.z | 
user@x.y.z \\[0.8cm]
\today\\}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]